# Moving elements between Twitter Bootstrap lists with different entry stile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 Twitter Bootstrap lists of elements:

- One is a list of available elements which can be dragged to the second list (its like a shop)
- The other list stores copies of elements from the first list (like a shopping cart)

There is an additional difference between both tables: Entries on the "shopping cart list" have a badge (to indicate the amount of each item) and a delete button.

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">list1 (cart)</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul id="list1" class="list-group">
            <li id="item1" href="#" class="list-group-item">Item1 <span id="badge" class="badge">5</span>
 <i class="fa fa-remove fa-2x pull-right" style="color: red;"></i>

            </li>
            <li id="item2" href="#" class="list-group-item">Item2 <span id="badge" class="badge">-3</span>
 <i class="fa fa-remove fa-2x pull-right" style="color: red;"></i>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">list2 (shop)</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul id="list2" class="list-group">
            <li href="#" class="list-group-item">Item1</li>
            <li href="#" class="list-group-item">Item2</li>
            <li href="#" class="list-group-item">Item3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// Create list of instances
var list1_element = document.getElementById("list1");
var list1 = new Sortable(list1_element, {
    group: {
        name: "my_group",
        pull: true,
        put: true
    },

    // Called by any change to the list (add / update / remove)
    onSort: function (event) {
        console.log('Change performed to list1');
    },
});

// Create list 2
var list2_element = document.getElementById("list2");
var list2 = new Sortable(list2_element, {
    group: {
        name: "my_group",
        pull: 'clone',
        put: false
    },
    sort: false
});

// Configure click action over the badges
jQuery(".badge").click(function () {
    console.log('Clicked badge');
});

// Configure click action over the remove buttons
jQuery(".icon-remove").click(function () {
    console.log('Clicked remove button');
    $(this).closest("li").remove();
});
```

The problem is that initial items do have the badge and the delete button, but items dragged from the "shop list" are stored at the other list without badge or delete button.

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/on2L7fdm/1/) to show current status.

Any idea of how to fix it?

BONUS: I'm still figguring out how to make the delete icon appear at the right of the badge and better centered in height. Any idea for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the element that you have dragged with your custom HTML, to show the badge and the remove icon.

UPDATED

After you created the new i element, you need to bind the click() for it. 
I've updated my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bellu/on2L7fdm/7/).

```
  ...
  onSort: function (event) {
    ///add the badge
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML +"1";
    span.className = span.className + " badge";
    event.item.appendChild(span);

    ///add remove icon
    var i = document.createElement("i");
    i.style.color='red';
    i.className = i.className + " fa fa-remove fa-2x pull-right";
    event.item.appendChild(i);

    //bind the new icon element
    jQuery(i).click(function () {
            console.log('Clicked the new remove button');
            $(this).closest("li").remove();
     });

    //in event you have a lot of information see it in the console
    console.log(event);
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Works perfectly but for one detail: the close button is not working for the new added rows. In fact the ones I put as example only work if the function Query(".icon-remove").click is changed for Query(".fa-remove").click (a typo when creating the Fidle). This way, the default can be erased, but the new added ones no. How to fix this?

Comment: I've updated my FIDDLE, now you will be able to erased all the rows.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Just for learning: why do the existing function affecting all elements from class ".fa-remove" don't apply to dinamically added elements?

Comment: @RomanRdgz This happened because the script in the fiddle execute the script in script.js one time onLoad event.
But initially the element that you create after,dragging into the list1(cart), doesn't exist, so the event handler for the click event isn't bind.
So you need to attach the click event handler to the new element when you create it.